# use .replace() on only one character of a string with repetitive characters

Tags: python, string, replace

I have this hangman problem and in this part, I'm trying to replace the placeholder `'_ '` with the character that they've correctly guessed. e.g. if `secretWord = 'lettuce'`, and they've guessed `e`, I want it to go through secretWord and check if e is in it, and then replace that `'_ '` with `e`, so it returns
`_ e_ _ _ _ e`

my code goes:

## create a placeholder string representation of `secretWord`

```
so Far = '' 
for char in secretWord:
    soFar = soFar + '_ '
```

## check/replace the placeholder with the correct character

```
for char in secretWord:
    if char in lettersGuessed:
    soFar.replace('_ ', str(char))
print soFar
```

But in pythontutor.com, where `secretWord = 'lettuce'` and `lettersGuessed =  ['z', 'x', 'q', 'l', 'e', 't', 't', 'u', 'c', 'e']` my output was:

```
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    l l l l l l l 
    l l l l l l l
    l l l l l l l 
    l l l l l l l 
    l l l l l l l 
    l l l l l l l 
    l l l l l l l
```

So basically, it saw that `l` was in letters guessed, and since it is supposed to replace `'_ '` with that character, it replaced all of them. But I just want it to do it that once (and again, if it is in `secretWord` again). And then it couldn't replace any of the other characters because none of them were `'_ '`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `replace` when you're trying to replace a character at a certain *position*; it's only for when you want to replace all characters, at all indexes, that match a certain value.

The way to replace a character at an index is with slicing:

```
soFar = soFar[:index] + newChar + soFar[index+1:]
```

In this case, each character in secretWord matches *two* characters in soFar, so you have to double those:

```
soFar = soFar[:index*2] + newChar + soFar[index*2+1:]
```

---

But how do you *know* the index? Not by calling `index` on the string—that will have the same problem, returning the index of the first character with that value, not the one you want. Use the `enumerate` function to keep count for you as you go along:

```
for index, char in enumerate(secretWord):
```

---

As kevinsa5 suggests, if you'd used a list instead of a string, you would make this simpler:

```
soFar = []
for char in secretWord:
    soFar.append('_')
```

Now, the replacement is just:

```
soFar[index] = char
```

However, if you print that out as a string, it'll look like `['_', '_']` rather than `_ _`. To turn it into a nice string, you need to use the `join` method:

```
print ' '.join(soFar)
```

Comment: Because they want mutability, they might as well just use lists of characters, no? Then you can avoid the ugly (to me) slicing.

Comment: @kevinsa5: Yes, good point; let me edit that into the answer.

Comment: *it's only for when you want to replace all characters, at all indexes, that match a certain value* - nitpick on "at all indexes" since the number of replacements can be specified...

Comment: I suppose I was just being stubborn and trying to fix it using strings as that's how I started the problem. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list, rather than a string:

```
soFar = [char if char in lettersGuessed else '_' for char in secretWord]
print(' '.join(soFar))
```

Also, it would be better to have `lettersGuessed` be a `set` rather than a `list`. Since you care only about membership in the set, and it is appropriate for `lettersGuessed` to only contain unique items.

Comment: You need a count of guesses. If the game is designed to play nice by not charging repeat guesses against you (or to reject them as error moves), that's fine, but looking at the examples in the OP's question, I'm not sure he wants that—he's clearly typed `e` and `t` multiple times, and isn't surprised that it kept track of that. Meanwhile, depending on your intended interface, you might want to preserve order. A `Counter`, `OrderedSet`, or `OrderedCounter` would solve the former, the latter, or both better than a `list` would, but that may be beyond novice territory.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is now, you are replacing every single `'_'` with the first guessed letter that appears in the `secretWord`. So, when the guessed `l`, it filled in every `_` with `l`.

What you can do instead:

```
for index, char in enumerate(secretWord):
    if char in lettersGuessed:
    soFar = soFar[:index-1]+char+soFar[index+1:]
print soFar
```

Comment: But `soFar[index]` is going to be `_`, so this will do the same thing he's already doing.

Comment: That's true, good spot. This is mostly to show off enumerate, which everyone proceeded to use in their answer, which is probably the best way for the OP to change as little as possible and still have their code work

Comment: Think you might need to check the indentation on this.

Comment: @ChrisProsser: The broken indentation is copied as-is from the OP's code. It should still be fixed, of course, just don't blame Alex. (Also, FWIW, I think the OP's code is actually a tabs-spaces case where it *looks* broken but works anyway… but that obviously doesn't mean it isn't wrong; code has to be readable to humans, not just interpreters.)

Answer (score 0):

Though abarnert has given you a neat solution already,

I approached this problem by tracking "unguessed_letters" and using "maketrans"

Solution:

```
from string import maketrans    
def process_guess(secret_word, unguessed_letters, guess):
    if guess in secret_word:
        unguessed_letters = unguessed_letters.replace(guess, '')
    trantab = maketrans(unguessed_letters, "_"*len(unguessed_letters))
    return secret_word.translate(trantab), unguessed_letters
```

Usage Demonstration:

```
secret_word = "lettuce"
unguessed_letters = secret_word
lettersGuessed = ['z', 'x', 'q', 'l', 'e', 't', 't', 'u', 'c', 'e']
for i in lettersGuessed:
    secret_mask, unguessed_letters = process_guess(secret_word, unguessed_letters, i)
    print secret_mask
```

Execution Output:

```
$ python j.py 
_______
_______
_______
l______
le____e
lett__e
lett__e
lettu_e
lettuce
lettuce
```